# Glide cannot resolve method 'into(android.widget.TextView)'

Tags: android, android-glide

I use the following code but it is saying that it cannot resolve into() method. but in other project is work

```
Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
                .load(currentNews.getmThumbnail())
                .into(holder.thumbnailImageView);
```

and this my gradle dependencies

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Comment: is holder.thumbnailImageView a `ImageView` or  `TextView`

Comment: is a `ImageView`

Comment: I've found the problem, thank you